# Map the share to unassigned drive letter in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am mapping my network drive using powershell like follows.

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive("r:", "$Folder","FALSE","Domain\UserName", "Password")
```

But here i am sending drive letter as `r:` . If `r:` drive is already utilized it would fail.

Is there any way to map drive to unassigned drive letter. ( For ex. If `R:` is already assigned but `S:` is not then it should map to S: drive automatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you'll need to get the next available drive letter. Here's an example from [Archive of PowerShell.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20091024144040/http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/10/21/find-next-available-drive-letter.aspx):

```
function Get-NextFreeDrive {
  68..90 | ForEach-Object { "$([char]$_):" } | 
  Where-Object { 'h:', 'k:', 'z:' -notcontains $_  } | 
  Where-Object { 
    (new-object System.IO.DriveInfo $_).DriveType -eq 'noRootdirectory' 
  }
}
```

From PowerShell.com:

> It starts by enumerating ASCII codes for letters D: through Z:. The
>   pipeline will then convert those ASCII codes into drive letters. Next,
>   check out how the pipeline uses an exclusion list with drives you do
>   not want to use for mapping (optional). In this example, drive letters
>   h:, k:, and z: are never used. Finally, the pipeline uses a .NET
>   DriveInfo object to check whether the drive is in use or not.

```
$net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
$net.MapNetworkDrive((Get-NextFreeDrive)[0], "$Folder","FALSE","Domain\UserName", "Password")
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this way, for the following reasons:

It doesn't require WMI, just regular powershell cmdlets
It is very clear and easy to read
It easily allows you to exclude specific driveletters
It easily allows you to order the driveletters in any order you would like
It finds the first non used driveletter and maps it, and then it is finished.

```
$share="\\Server\Share"
$drvlist=(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem).Name
Foreach ($drvletter in "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()) {
    If ($drvlist -notcontains $drvletter) {
        $drv=New-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem -Name $drvletter -Root $share
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't require WMI either. It does however require `WScript.Network` because **at the time it was written** (PoSH v2 - check the date), `New-PSDrive`'s support for `-credential` was broken and there was no other way to supply alternate credentials for mapping a drive.