# Getting a free drive letter

Tags: powershell

I saw the `Get-NextFreeDrive` function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799643/map-the-share-to-unassigned-drive-letter-in-powershell/8799797#8799797) and I wondered if there was a more efficient way to do this. It appears that the function in the linked answer keeps going through all the letters even if it has already found a free drive letter.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At PowerShell Magazine, we ran a brain teaser contest to find out the shortest answer to your question. Check this:

https://powershellmagazine.com/post/2012-01-12-find-an-unused-drive-letter/

There are several answers but here is my fav one:

```
ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | random
```

Comment: This just gets a random available drive letter, not the first available.

Comment: @Nick - That can be fixed by replacing `random` with `select -First 1`

Comment: We are just using RegEx there. Function: gets appended with letter from d to z and then a :.

Comment: @ravikanth ah, it searches the PS drive called ["function:"](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-providers/) using [wildcard syntax](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692793.aspx). There is a function for every possible drive letter, whether the path exists or not. Tricky!

Comment: This answer is misleading, it will possible return existing drives (like a cd-rom) with no media in them. Here's a better version: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/202.aspx

Comment: Victor Grigoriu: That issue is easily avoided: rather than `random` use `select -Last 1`

Comment: @ravikanth, it works but not a powershell style.

Answer (score 5):

My two cents:

```
get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | select -expand DeviceID -Last 1 | 
% { [char]([int][char]$_[0]  + 1) + $_[1] }
```

Range of valid `[CHAR]` is `68..90`, adding a check if `[char]$_[0] -gt 90` avoid unexpected results.
In case some unit is a mapped network drive it return always the major successive, ex.:

```
c: system drive
d: cd/dvd
r: network mapped drive
```

the command return `s:` and not `e:` as [string]

This give the first free drive letter ( a little ugly.. someone can do it better IMO):

```
$l = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | select -expand DeviceID  | % { $_[0] }
$s = [int][char]$l[0]
foreach ( $let in $l )
{
    if ([int][char]$let -ne $s)
    {
        $ret = [char]$s +":"
        break
    }

    $s+=1    
}
$ret
```

Answer (score 5):

I like this way, for the following reasons:

1. It doesn't require WMI, just regular powershell cmdlets
2. It is very clear and easy to read
3. It easily allows you to exclude specific driveletters
4. It easily allows you to order the driveletters in any order you would like
5. It finds the first non used driveletter and maps it, and then it is finished.

   ```
   $share="\\Server\Share"
   $drvlist=(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem).Name
   Foreach ($drvletter in "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray()) {
       If ($drvlist -notcontains $drvletter) {
           $drv=New-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem -Name $drvletter -Root $share
           break
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with.  I need the last available drive letter from A to Z.

```
$AllLetters = 65..90 | ForEach-Object {[char]$_ + ":"}
$UsedLetters = get-wmiobject win32_logicaldisk | select -expand deviceid
$FreeLetters = $AllLetters | Where-Object {$UsedLetters -notcontains $_}
$FreeLetters | select-object -last 1
```

- This gets an array of letters A..Z
- Then gets an array of the letters already in use from WMI
- Next produces an array of letters not in use using the comparison operator -notcontains
- Finally outputs a single letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
$taken = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Select -expand DeviceID
$letter = 65..90 | ForEach-Object{ [char]$_ + ":" }
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $letter -DifferenceObject $taken)[1].InputObject
```

Just for fun to shave an extra line of code (lol). If you wanted to be cloppy as heck you could skip instantiating variables and just pipe those directly into -Ref and -Diff directly, probably ought to be slapped for doing that though. :)

Selects [1] to avoid getting the A: drive just in case that might complicate matters.

Answer (score 1):

I had to Write a function that works with Powershell V2.0.
The following Function will Return the next available letter, it also can get an exclude letter as parameter:

```
Function AvailableDriveLetter ()
{
param ([char]$ExcludedLetter)
$Letter = [int][char]'C'
$i = @()
#getting all the used Drive letters reported by the Operating System
$(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem) | %{$i += $_.name}
#Adding the excluded letter
$i+=$ExcludedLetter
while($i -contains $([char]$Letter)){$Letter++}
Return $([char]$Letter)
}
```

Let's say Your OS reports drive-letters C:,E:,F: and G: as being used.

Running: *$First = AvailableDriveLetter* ,Will result in $First containing 'D'

Running: *$Sec = AvailableDriveLetter -ExcludedLetter $First* ,Will result in $Sec containing 'H'

Answer (score 1):

Another way...

```
$DriveList = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem | foreach({($_.Root).Replace(":\","")})
$AllDrives = [char[]]([int][char]'E'..[int][char]'Z')
$NextDriveLetter = ($AllDrives | Where-Object { $DriveList -notcontains $_ } | Select-Object -First 1) + ":"
```

Answer (score 1):

I found to my own cost that the currently accepted answer *(ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | random)* can indeed return things like CD drives.

I've made this one to exclude any local drives from the array:

```
"$([char[]]([char]'D'..[char]'Z')|Where-Object {((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk).DeviceID).replace(':','') -notcontains $_ }|Select-Object -first 1):"
```

It will return the first available letter. If you'd prefer the last available letter just change `Select-Object -first 1` to `Select-Object -last 1`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that Test-Path evaluates my empty CD-Drive as False, here is another alternative that will compare every letter in the alphabeth until it finds one that doesn't exist in filesystem, then returns that drive as output.

```
$DriveLetter = [int][char]'C'
WHILE((Get-PSDrive -PSProvider filesystem).Name -contains [char]$DriveLetter){$DriveLetter++}
Write-Host "$([char]$Driveletter):"
```

Answer (score 0):

just going to add one that works for remote drive letters
$computer will be the input and $driveletter would contain the next available drive on the remote computer

```
67..90 | foreach {if(((GWmi win32_logicaldisk -computer $computer -Property DeviceID).deviceID).Substring(0,1) -notcontains [char]$_){$driveLetter = [char]$_; break}}
```

might be able to shorten that but at that length its clear to see whats going on

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit like a "me too" answer, but I noticed that all the other answers use `-contains` or `-notcontains` and I just didn't like those solutions.  So this may not be terribly efficient, but I like it better.  The purpose of this code (for me) was to find the first drive that I can use to create a drive mapping.

```
$FreeDrive=Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Where-Object { ($_ -ne "A") -and ($_ -ne "B") -and ($_ -ne "C") } | ForEach-Object { [System.Convert]::ToByte([System.Convert]::ToChar($_)) }
$FreeDrive=@($FreeDrive)
if (($FreeDrive.Count -eq 1) -and ($FreeDrive[0] -ne "Z")) { $FreeDrive=[System.Convert]::ToChar($FreeDrive[0]+1) }
$j=0
while ((($FreeDrive[$j]+1) -eq $FreeDrive[$j+1]) -and ($j -lt ($FreeDrive.Count-1))) { $j++ }
$FreeDrive=[System.Convert]::ToChar($FreeDrive[$j]+1)
$FreeDrive
```

Answer (score 0):

This is powershell style

```
$FreeDriveLetter = ('Z'..'A') | ForEach-Object{ if( !( test-path -path ( $_ + ":" ) )){ $_; break }}
```