# How to obtain path with mapped network drive from .NET file dialog

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, openfiledialog

I see many questions on how to get UNC paths from mapped drive letters, but none on the reverse problem.

On different Windows 7 Enterprise machines, I'm getting different answers for the `FileName` of `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` instances with the exact same input, current directory, and network drive mapping:

1. one computer answers with a UNC path

   ```
   PS A:\Liver\Department\Records\check log> .\sign-log.ps1
   VERBOSE: Writing signature to \\liver53-pc.ad.institute.edu\Documents\Liver\Department\Records\check log\00\check log.xlsx.sig
   ```
2. others answer with a mapped drive path

   ```
   PS A:\Liver\Department\Records\check log> .\sign-log.ps1
   VERBOSE: Writing signature to A:\Liver\Department\Records\check log\00\check log.xlsx.sig
   ```

I need every computer to answer with mapped drive paths: the command-line program receiving the `FileName` doesn't understand UNC paths.
Here are the contents of `sign-log.ps1`:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
function Sign-Log ($file = '.\check-log.xlsx') {
    $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        Title = 'Select'
        ; InitialDirectory = (Get-Location).Path
        ; Filename = 'check log.xlsx'
        ; Filter = 'Excel Spreadsheet (*.xlsx;*.xls)|*.xlsx;*.xls|Any file (*.*)|*.*'
        ; ShowHelp = $true
    }
    if ($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK) {
        $file = $FileBrowser.FileName
        $dest = $file + '.sig'
        if (Test-Path -Path $dest) {
            Write-Verbose -Message ('Appending signature to {0}' -f $dest)
            Add-Content -Path $dest -Value (gpg '-ao' '-' '-b' $file)
        } else {
            Write-Verbose -Message ('Writing signature to {0}' -f $dest)
            gpg '-ao' $dest '-b' $file
        }
        gpg '--verify' $dest
    }
    $FileBrowser.Dispose()
}
Sign-Log
```

What do I need to do to always get mapped drive paths?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best bet would be to test for a UNC path being returned, and if so, temporarily map it to a drive letter, then send that to `gpg`. Maybe something like this:

```powershell
if (([uri]$dest).IsUnc) {
    $destPath = $dest | Split-Path -Parent
    # Find a free drive letter
    $letter = ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | Select-Object -Last 1
    New-PSDrive -Name $letter[0] -Root $destPath -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem
    $dest = $destPath | Join-Path -ChildPath $file
}

# Then after you're done calling gpg:
if ($destPath) {
    Remove-PSDrive -Name $letter[0] -Force
}
```

This is untested..

The one-liner for getting the free drive letter came from here: [Getting a free drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488030/getting-a-free-drive-letter)

[New-PSDrive Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx)

[Remove-PSDrive Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849760.aspx)