# A map network drive not showed with Powershell, but is with VBS?

Tags: powershell, smb

I have made a function with powershell that list all the available drive letters for mapping a new drive. This is working just fine at work(On a domain, Win 7, 64 bit).
But here at home, at my private computer(not on a domain, Win 8.1, 64 bit) I can't get Powershell to see my Map Drive R:.
It's there, in explore and when I use VBS:

```
Net use r:
  Local name        R:
  Remote name       \\10.10.10.10\Folder
  Resource type     Disk
  The command completed successfully.
```

In powershell I use the following code:

```
Get-PSDrive | Where-Object name -EQ 'r'
```

And Im not getting any result back. If I look in WMI, I'm still not getting anything. Here I use the following code:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_LogicalDisk | Where-Object DeviceID -EQ 'r:'
```

I found this link, [Getting a free drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488030/getting-a-free-drive-letter), and even with this code, it's still select my R:\ as an available drive letter.

Can some point me a the right direction, please :-) ?

*Bonus info:*

At work all drives are mappet to windows computers.

At home my r:\ is mappet to a linux, nas server(Qnap TS 410).

```
Get-SMBshare
```

Don't show the R: drive ether.

Comment: Do you attempt to view the drive in the same session that you created it with `net use`? If you do that the current session is not aware of the mapping. One way to address that is start another powershell session. Or depending you could create it with `New-PSdrive`

Comment: Are you running with UAC enabled? If so, you're account has two logon sessions - one for standard user and one for elevated/admin use.  A share created in one is not visible in the other.

Comment: @KeithHill Sorry for not  mention it. If I run the same command get-PSdrive, without running the shell as admin, I get the R drive.

But what I don't understand is, if I run Get-PSdrive and Net use R: in the same shell as admin, it's only the net use that return the drive R.
How can Net use return R, and PS can't?

It's all done in the same Shell as admin?
I understand the different sessions part, as admin, and with out admin, but in my world, this should also affect net use.

UAC is on the lowest setting, "Never notify me when:", so it's most likely not it, causing this.

Comment: If I try the same thing at home (workgroup) - net use r ... in a non-elevated prompt, I can see it in that (and other non-elevated) sessions with Get-PSDrive. However, if I launch a PowerShell session elevated, neither net use or Get-PSDrive show the drive.  How did you create the drive mapping?

Comment: I used windows GUI explore to do it.
Map network drive -> selected a drive -> type in a UNC -> set a check in "reconnect at logon" -> and made the "Connect using different credentials" unchect.

So no spherical way of doing this.
I can't say if it was before or after I turned off UAC.

But I don't understand why net use can see the drive and PS can't. Where does Net Use get this information from?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has issued a knowledge base article (KB3035277) about the issue you reported:

[Mapped drives are not available from an elevated prompt when UAC is configured to "Prompt for credentials" in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3035277/mapped-drives-are-not-available-from-an-elevated-prompt-when-uac-is-co)

In the article Microsoft confirms that this is a problem in a number of listed Microsoft products (including Windows 8.1) and they offer two different work arounds.