# How do I tell if a drive is a dvd or virtual drive, test-path isn't enough?

Tags: powershell

As part of learning to use PowerShell, I have been examining how to locate a free drive letter. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488030/getting-a-free-drive-letter/12488560) is a great startpoint: 
However, if there is a DVD drive and/or a virtual drive on the PC, then the really neat pipeline

```
ls function:[d-z]: -n | where { !(test-path $_) }
```

will claim that the letters for those drives are free (because there is nothing mounted). Is there some simple algorihmic way to take those drives out of the list - assuming that the command must work on all machines, and not use explicit knowledge of what drives exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WMI class `Win32_CDROMDrive` already knows the cd/dvd rom drives that exist. Using the information from that we can exclude those generate drive list.

```psh
$cddrives = (Get-WmiObject Win32_CDROMDrive).Drive
ls function:[d-z]: -N | Where-Object {$cddrives -notcontains $_ -and !(test-path $_)}
```

FYI `ls` = `Get-ChildItem` and `-N` is the unambiguous short reference to the parameter `-Name`

Comment: BTW I just discovered a similar command `(Get-CimInstance -class cim_cdromdrive).Drive` with hints that this is the direction Microsoft is going for access to WMI data.