# Powershell Function Not Mapping Drive When Called

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a New-PSDrive and mapping over a shared drive. The code runs fine outside of the function as is, but whenever its wrapped within a function I see it try to map the drive. When I run `Get-PSDrive`, the specified shared drive is not listed.

This is the total opposite when running the script outside of the function, I can definitely see the drive mapping over to shared folder after running `Get-PSDrive` and it's also listed/showing under Computer within Folder Explorer.

```
function MapDrive {

# creates an array of available Drive Letters 
$driveArray = @("A","B","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z")

# check every letter in the array if its available then create a New-PSDrive
foreach ($letter in $driveArray) {
    If (!(Test-Path "$letter`:")) {
        New-PSDrive -Name $letter -Root "\\my_server_ip\shared_folder" -Persist -PSProvider Filesystem -Credential (Get-Credential)
        break
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "No available Drives."
        break
    }
}

}

MapDrive

Get-PSDrive
```

Comment: try `-scope Global`

Comment: I'm new to scripting & working with Powershell I really do appreciate it SimonS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer from [Getting a free drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488030/getting-a-free-drive-letter) :

```
$letter = Get-ChildItem function:[f-z]: -n | Where { !(Test-Path $_) } | select -First 1

New-PSDrive -Name ($letter)[0] -Root "\\my_server_ip\shared_folder" -Persist -PSProvider Filesystem -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: This works as well thank you James! This method is definitely another way to implement this I really appreciate it.