# Automatically create drive mappings for available network shares

Tags: powershell, network-share, drive-mapping

Current script is:

`cmdkey /add:(name of my NAS) /user:network\(username on NAS) /pass:(password for username on NAS)`

`New-PSDrive -Name "E" -Root "\\(name of my NAS)\(name of shared folder)" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"`

This will map one of the shared folders that the user has access to on the NAS as a local drive on the PC. Of course if there are more than 1 shared folders the user has access to on the NAS and wants them mapped, then the

`New-PSDrive -Name "E" -Root "\\(name of my NAS)\(name of shared folder)" -Persist -PSProvider "FileSystem"`

part needs to be used/written again but now with a different letter than "E"

This is pretty complicated even on just a select few PCs. I want to rewrite the script in a way that once the system knows the NAS user account (username + password), it will automatically map all the network folders they have access to as local drives on the PC.

Any ideas how this could work? I know in AD you have a way to do this but none of my PCs are domain-joined and I don't have an AD domain.

Comment: [Getting a free drive letter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12488030/1701026)

Comment: @iRon  that doesn't AT ALL relate to what I'm looking for, unless you care to elab